# Android Studio 1.1.0 does not get references of aar file build from 1.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I made a module library in android studio 1.0.0. From that I took the .aar file & used it to other project. But after updating my android studio to 1.1.0 when I import it, I does not get any reference from it.

Doing some research I found that it is for gradle build version in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
}
```

If downgrade it to 1.0.0 then any references from .aar file(1.0.0) are found. But I think this is not best solution. So, any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

in project window (press `Alt+1`) > switch to `Project` view (from top of this window), create a folder in `app` by name `aar`.
make a copy from `myLibrary.aar` and put in `app/aar`. then

write below code in `MyProject > build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'aar'
        }
    }
}
```

and write below code in `MyProject/app > build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile(name: 'myLibrary', ext: 'aar')
}
```

it's working for me! :)