# Not able to access class from .aar file

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to access methods of a class which reside inside a `.aar` file.
I am following @PoliceEstebi's answer from [how to import .aar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826717/how-to-import-a-aar-file-into-android-studio-1-1-0-and-use-it-in-my-code).

But still I am not able to access class methods from the `.aar` file.

If anyone can help that would be great!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst

Comment: If you are using Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, this simple Gradle setup worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081429/android-studio-cannot-resolve-symbols-from-imported-aar-module/50139545#50139545

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found solution even on Gradle 1.1.0.
I found help from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803565/android-studio-1-1-0-does-not-get-references-of-aar-file-build-from-1-0-0) by @AliDK answer.

create a folder in `app` by name `aar`.

make a copy from `myLibrary.aar` and put in `app/aar`. then

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'aar'
    }
  }
}
```

and write below code in `MyProject/app > build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
...
compile(name: 'myLibrary', ext: 'aar')
}
```

And it worked for me after spending 2 days.

Thanks to @AliDK..

I hope it would work for others too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how to call classes from .aar file?

Comment: Worked for me on Android Studio 3.0. Change suggested in app/build.gradle was not required in my case.

Comment: But how to call the aar class method in the App.

I get `error: cannot find symbol`